# Save fragment state on orientation change when using different layouts for different orientations

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I have different layouts for portrait and landscape mode. `layout\activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And `layout-large\activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentorientationchangetest.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentorientationchangetest.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My fragments are same, `fragment1.xml` and `fragment2.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is when I enter some text in edit text in my fragments and I rotate the screen, the edit text doesn't lose its input text.

Since the fragments in portrait and landscape mode are not one instance, I cannot use `setRetaintInstance` or `onSaveInstanceState`. How can I do that without defining two activities and without use of `onConfigurationChanged`?

**Note:** Without adding any code, each fragment saves its data. So If I enter some text in fragment2 in portrait mode and rotate to landscape and rotate to portrait mode again, I see the entered text.

Comment: "What I want is when I enter some text in edit text in my fragments and I rotate the screen, the edit text doesn't lose its input text." and "Note: Without adding any code, each fragment saves its data. So If I enter some text in fragment2 in portrait mode and rotate to landscape and rotate to portrait mode again, I see the entered text." **so what is the question?** and **side note: if you are going to edit your question add Edit or Update after some one answered**

Comment: @mmlooloo I am in portrait mode. I enter some text in edit text, then rotate to landscape. I don't see entered text, then rotate the screen again to portrait mode and I see entered text. What should I do to see entered text when going from land to port and viceversa?

Comment: because your fragments are not one instance your problem actually falls in category of fragment communication and I think my solution is the simplest one. you can wait for others but my solution is my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I code more I sometimes ignore simple idea like:

```
SharedPreferences myText = getSharedPreferences("txt", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("userText", "Your text that you want to save");
editor.commit();
```

and reading:

```
SharedPreferences myText = context.getSharedPreferences("txt", 0);
String userInput = myText .getString("userText", "");
```

then set your editText according to `userInput`.

Comment: I know it is possible by using other components such as `SharedPreferences` or `BroadCastReceiver` or have static reference to fragment instances. But I think they are not good ideas because they are not made for this case.

Comment: without `onSaveInstanceState` and `setRetaintInstance` your last choice is `SharedPreferences` other component that you mentioned is not suited at all and also dangerous like "have static reference to fragment instances"

Comment: However I did it by using `onSaveInstanceState` in main activity not fragments by checking which fragment is showing, I was thinking there must be another handy way to do that.